# Llamadas a metodos de clases externas en funciones lambda java

Tags: java, lambda

En un principio tenia una clase con una función lambda en una clase java.

```
        final Map<String, UserBean> users = persons.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> !entry.getValue().getIsActive().booleanValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                entry -> entry.getKey()
                , entry -> entry.getValue()));
```

Pero sonar me marcaba una sugerencia: ***Lambdas should be replaced with method references***

Entonces me puse a a sacar a metodos externos. Empezé añadiendo a la misma clase donde estaba la lambda una función que me devolvia la key. Y actualice la lambda de la siguiente forma:

```
        final Map<String, UserBean> users = persons.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> !entry.getValue().getIsActive().booleanValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    this::<String>getEntryKey
                    , entry -> entry.getValue()));
```

Esto me funcionaba perfectamente y la sugerencia de sonar solamente me la marcaba en la arrow que se encontraba en la linea de abajo de la sentencia que modifiqué. el tema es que me di cuenta que esta advertencia se me repetia en muchos lugares del código. Entonces m puse a hacer una clase utilidad para no repetir codigo.

la clase de utilidad que tengo cuenta con dos métodos para obtener las keys y los values de un mapa:

```
public class LambdaUtils {

private static final LambdaUtils INSTANCE = new LambdaUtils();

public static LambdaUtils getInstance() {
    return LambdaUtils.INSTANCE;
}

public <K> K getEntryKey(Entry<K, ?> entry) {
    return entry.getKey();
}

public <V> V getEntryValue(Entry<?, V> entry) {
    return entry.getValue();
}
}
```

El problema es que ahora no se como añadir esa llamda a los metodos de la clase de utilidad dentro de la lambda.

```
    final Map<String, UserBean> users = persons.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> !entry.getValue().getIsActive().booleanValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    this::LambdaUtils.getInstance().getEntryKey() //ERROR
                    , entry -> entry.getValue()));
```

Como puedo hacer la llamada a ese metodo externo dentro de una lambda?

Comment: Veo que en tu clase `LambdaUtils` en el metodo `getEntryKey` esperas recibir un `Entry` pero según veo en el ultimo trozo de código, cuando llamas al método, no le pasas el Entry

Comment: Si cierto, Acabo de probar pasandole entry, this y el ide sigue quejandose por que esta mal formado. ¿Como debría hacerlo? Un saludo

Comment: `LamdaUtils` es singleton?

Comment: @DavidDPG obtengo instancias únicas de la clase llamando a su getInstance. Se cargaría la clase para su uso y al salir de la clase de la lamba la instancia desaparecería.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creo que te estás complicando la vida mucho. De la [documentación de oracle sobre referencias a métodos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) se puede extraer una tabla que explica qué tipos de referencias se pueden usar y su sintaxis:

```
Método estático                             -> ClaseContenedora::metodoEstatico
Método de instancia de un objeto particular -> instanciaDelObjeto::metodoDeInstancia
Método de instancia de un *tipo* particular -> ClaseDelTipoDeInstancia::metodoDeInstancia
Constructor                                 -> NombreDeLaClase::new
```

En tu caso quieres extraer clave y valor de tus entradas, por lo que te propongo que uses la tercera opción de la tabla con el tipo `Map.Entry`:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue);
```

Comment: Este patrón todavía me cuesta visualizar y entender. Aunque reconozco que una vez captado es muy cómodo de leer y programar. Funciona perfectamente. Gracias por la ayuda !!!